# How can I create a dropdown menu after clicking on an image? [bootstrap/angular]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I did some trials adding a dropdown class, but I don't know where to begin. Here's the small snipper of code for what I want to add a dropdown menu:

```
<span
  id="dropdown-info"
  ng-init= "myVar='images/info_icon_off.png'" 
  ng-mouseover="myVar='images/info_icon_on.png'" 
  ng-mouseout="myVar='images/info_icon_off.png'"
  ng-click="doSomething()">
    <img class="info-icon" ng-src="{{myVar}}" alt="Information" width="10" height="10">
</span>
```

Comment: You want to create a dropdown ? dynamically or show one that already exists ? And where do you want that dropdown to appear ?

Comment: dynamically, and underneath the image

Comment: I suggest putting your span into a directive. then in the link function you could a add dynamically the  drop-down under the image using Angular's jqLite. But if the structure of the dropdown can be pre-written and only its data is dynamic i'd suggest you hidding it with ng-if and populating its options with a variable

Comment: could you kindly share how to do so??! this might be the answer ive been looking for

Answer (score 1):

If You are using bootstrap that that's it... You can do ng-repeat with li to load list dynamically.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
<img src="https://c1.iggcdn.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/c_limit,w_620/v1456219661/avvcx99jxynsu2svk9po.png" class=" dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" /> 
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I suggest putting your span into a directive. then in the link function you could a add dynamically the drop-down under the image using Angular's jqLite. But if the structure of the dropdown can be pre-written and only its data is dynamic i'd suggest you hidding it with ng-if and populating its options with a variable

```
<span
  id="dropdown-info"
  ng-init= "myVar='images/info_icon_off.png'" 
  ng-mouseover="myVar='images/info_icon_on.png'" 
  ng-mouseout="myVar='images/info_icon_off.png'"
  ng-click="doSomething()">
    <img class="info-icon" ng-src="{{myVar}}" alt="Information" width="10" height="10">
    <select ng-if="showDropDown" ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
</span>
```

Then your JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('TestController', ['$scope',
     function($scope) {
         $scope.showDropDown = false;
         $scope.doSomething = function() {
             $scope.showDropDown = true;
         }
         $scope.items = [{
            id: 1,
            label: 'aLabel',
            subItem: { name: 'aSubItem' }
         }, {
            id: 2,
            label: 'bLabel',
            subItem: { name: 'bSubItem' }
         }];
     }
]);
```

this is a method without a directive. If you use many spans then this will not work. You would then need to use a directive and apply the same logic using `scope:{}`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working example:
https://embed.plnkr.co/jACJyC/

note: if you are working with angular6, the ClickOutside directive is declared in @NgModule 'declarations:'